# Trying to get Snapshot ARN from boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am ultimately trying to get/build a Snapshot's ARN so I can match it up to a detailed billing report. An example ResourceId that a Snapshot has a record for in the detailed billing report is like below.

```
arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:210987654321:snapshot/snap-12345678901234567
```

The `describe_snapshots()` method in boto3 only returns this information

```
{
    'Description': 'Created by CreateImage(i-12345678901234567) for ami-12345678901234567 from vol-12345678901234567', 
    'Encrypted': False, 
    'OwnerId': '210987654321', 
    'Progress': '100%', 
    'SnapshotId': 'snap-12345678901234567', 
    'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 22, 16, 24, 14, 564000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 
    'State': 'completed', 
    'VolumeId': 'vol-12345678901234567', 
    'VolumeSize': 8
}
```

Ultimately, the only information I'm missing is identifiying which region the snapshot was created in. If I am able to find that information somewhere, I would be able to build the ARN myself.

I've already thought of finding the region through grabbing the volume associated to the Snapshot, however, it seems like a snapshot can exist without a volume therefore would not be an ideal method to retrieve this information. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The region is the one that your boto3 script runs, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this question. My boto3 script can report on resources in every region.

Comment: So `describe_snapshots` is not region scoped? It returns snapshots from all available regions at the same time?

Comment: I just gave it a go, looks like it only returns it from us-east-2. Weird thing is I don't specify a region anywhere in my script. I could have sworn that other methods like describe_rds returns instances from all regions. Is there a way to filter `describe_snapshots` by region?

Comment: boto3 will take region from your aws credentails profile. In boto3, you can choose region explicitly using `ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')`.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to refactor it a bit using your method. I am not retrieving all snapshots from all regions! I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Comment: Marked as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

`describe_snapshots` returns snapshot from the **current region** only. Thus, by explicitly setting up the region, or using the default one from boto3, one can get the region required for the construction of ARN.

To get snapshots from multiple regions, one can **iterate over regions** of interest and use the `boto3.client` to get snapshots from different regions:

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='<region-name>')
```